# get php variable from dropdown without page submission

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get a value from a dropdown menu and pass it as a php variable and echo it (on the same page).

The dropdown displays the name of users, but select their username, which I want to echo. The purpose it to use the variable to perform other tasks, if I can echo it successfully.

I have used jquery and ajax to get the variable, without submitting the page. But I am unable to get the php variable.

I have read several examples, and used them, but somehow my code is not working. 
Can anyone please suggest where is the mistake?

Here is my code:

Test2.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="user" id="user" >
                  <option disabled selected value> - Select User - </option>
                  <?php 
                    $sql_select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, surname, fname FROM user WHERE v_flag != 0 ORDER BY surname ASC ");
                        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
                            $name = ($result['surname']. ', '.$result['fname']);
                            echo '<option value = " '.$result['username']. '">'.$name.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>                          
            </select>
        </td>                   
    </tr>
</table>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user").change(function() {        
  var user = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url:"test2.php",
        data:{username : user},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
            $("#usermame").html(response);
        }
      });
  });
}); 
</script>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];     
        if (!empty($username)){
            echo 'You have selected user: '.$username ;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_GET['username'])){//only echo user name if requested from js do not include header or footer 
        $username = $_GET['username'];     
        if (!empty($username)){
            echo 'You have selected user: '.$username ;
        }
    }else{//you can include here your headers
        ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="user" id="user" >
                  <option disabled selected value> - Select User - </option>
                  <?php 
                    $sql_select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, surname, fname FROM user WHERE v_flag != 0 ORDER BY surname ASC ");
                        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
                            $name = ($result['surname']. ', '.$result['fname']);
                            echo '<option value = " '.$result['username']. '">'.$name.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>                          
            </select>
        </td>  </tr> <tr><td> <span id="username">
         <?php if (isset($_POST['username'])){//show if submitted from html form
        $username = $_POST['username'];     
        if (!empty($username)){
            echo 'You have selected user: '.$username ;
        }
    }
    ?>  </span></td>                   
    </tr>
</table>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user").change(function() {        
  var user = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url:"test2.php?username="+user,
        success:function(response) {
            $("#username").html(response);
        }
      });
  });
}); 
</script>
 <?php
    //you can include here your footers

    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Mahfuzar, your solution works perfectly. Thanks..:)

Comment: you r welcome always feel free to ask question on here and knock me

Answer (score 0):

Your success handler is printing the request content in a html element with id username that do not exists on the page (at least not on this snippet)

```
success:function(response) {
        $("#usermame").html(response);
    }
```

Try to make the POST request to a different file because, in your case, the printed content will include the select (and the db request) again.

Comment: Hi Pedro, I understand that I have missed the div element where the html response was supposed to be passed. I used it as per your suggestion, but for some reason it still doesnt display the username!!. 
The main purpose to use it on the same page is that this page will appear in one of the (10) tab pages. As you know, page submission in a tabbed page scenario takes user back to the first tab. 
I believe one the way to resolve this, is to use JS to stay on the same tab page, but I am yet to explore that
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yep, I got it, sansam. I've deleted my answer because ir was very misleading. <div id="username"> shouldn't have any php code inside. The thing is we cannot know what's really going on for sure until you provide a little more info. 1. Are you calling jquery before the script? 2. Are you sure your AJAX call aims to the right file and or path? 3. Try $.post instead of $.ajax OR do $.ajax declaring method post (see + http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). 4. Use alerts or console.log -- do it a lot and check your Network tab on your browser console when you click on your users dropdown.